# Mapping security role to user/group mapping in RAD

Tags: websphere, ibm-rad

I am using a WebSphere Portal Server that runs some servlets as well. Previously, while I was using eclipse to develop I used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4913405/websphere-7-portal-servlet-checking-for-login-status-to-portal) solution to add roles in my web.xml file and map them in the integrated solutions console in the menu Applications > Application Types > Enterprise Applications > NAME_OF_APP > Security role to user/group mapping > Map users/groups. But now I am using the Rapid Application Developer and I can deploy directly through it. Unfortunately I can't use the the console anymore to create role mappings (as explained [here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=14421113) by TroyBishop in the second post nicely).

All over the internet people say, that I can create the role mappings using the file `META-INF/ibm-application-bnd.xml` / `META-INF/ibm-application-bnd.xmi`, but nobody seems to care about saying why that file is sometimes called .xmi and sometimes called .xml. Is this irrelevant or treated differently? And HOW the hack do I actually use the file? What's the format??

EDIT: And what about the ibm-web-bnd.xmi? Does that have to do with it as well?

Answer (score 1):

Go to server view in RAD, double click WebSphere to open its overview, uncheck "Minimize application files copied to the server". Save it. Remove and add again the application so changes take effect. That should solve all missing "OK/Apply/Save" buttons.

Comment: The other solution, if you find Ok/Apply anomalies is to switch to `Run server with resources on Server`, which works always however is a bit more heavyweight.

Answer (score 0):

The XMI files were meant for tools (and not for humans). XML files on the other hand were targetted.

For a long long time, till WAS V7, if i recall correctly, IBM used only the xmi files. It is with the advent of Java EE 5 that all the DDs were using XML instead of xmi.

Both the bnd and ext files used to use the XMI (XML Meta data interchange format). These are the IBM specific DDs.

Comment: ok. Do you also know something about the format? Or is a tool for editing these files shipped with RAD somewhere?

Comment: Hi Yankee, The tools  to use are RAD or AAT (Application Assembly tool). I am not sure if the names have changed in the recent past. AAT is a GUI tool that was bundled with a number of WAS versions.

Answer (score 0):

Details about difference between xmi and xml binding files (from the Infocenter)

> For IBM® extension and binding files, the `.xmi` or `.xml` file name
>   extension is different depending on whether you are using a pre-Java
>   EE 5 application or module or a Java EE 5 or later application or
>   module. An IBM extension or binding file is named ibm-*-ext.xmi or
>   ibm-*-bnd.xmi where * is the type of extension or binding file such as
>   app, application, ejb-jar, or web. The following conditions apply:
>
> - For an application or module that uses a **Java EE version prior to version 5**, the file extension must be `.xmi`.
> - For an application or module that uses **Java EE 5 or later**, the file extension must be `.xml`. If .xmi files are included with the
>     application or module, the product ignores the .xmi files.

To generate these files:

- If you have RAD - then select the project (Web, EJB), right click, then select `Java EE > Generate WebSphere Binding/Extension Deployment Descriptor`. If you don't see that option ensure that in project properties, Project Facets - you have WebSphere Coexistence/Extended facet enabled.
- If you use Eclipse - install WebSphere Developer Tools, which will enable same option

To edit bindings via console you have to change default publishing configuration in RAD as described in the [Rafael answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26069462/3701228).